# Masking out Text in Premiere Pro 2019

Tags: premiere, adobe, mask

I have end credits rolling over an image in Premiere Pro 19.

For a few seconds, I want a part of the image (the dog) to appear *over* the text. Therefore, I thought that I could mask the dog his head in the text frame, and then invert the mask. That way, only the dog head appears *over the text*. This worked at first. However, then I tried to apply the same formula again, somewhere earlier in the video by creating a second mask over the text, and then the effect failed. I do not understand why. I tried restarting Premiere, but it did not work.

I added a youtube video so that my settings are visible:

Thanks for all the help, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would duplicate a copy of your background (doggy) layer.  Put it on top of your text layer, then animate the mask on your foreground layer. So in total you have three layers:

```
V3 - foreground dog (masked)

V2 - text credits

V1 - background dog (and everything else)
```

(I reckon masking like this is easier in after effects but can be done in Premiere)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tomh.  Also, based on your sample, I would highly recommend you put some shadow around your text.  You have white text over a rapidly changing background video that often has a lot of very bright areas.  To keep the text readable, at a minimum, you want to put a shadow around your text (adjust opacity, width, etc. to taste).  I'd also put a thin black border around the text too; 1-3 pixel to start, but adjust to taste.  Finally, you might consider slighlty darkening the video layer (behind the text).